# Clear radio buttons of a submitted form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a form with two radio button groups.  When options are selected in each group they stay selected and change colour to show they have been selected.  However, when I try to reset the form using the **clear filters button** nothing happens.

I want the form to appear to the user as it did when it loaded for the first time (no selections, no colour change - just cleared.), any ideas?

I am using the onclick:"javascript:submit()" instead of a submit button, maybe this is causing an issue?

**The Code:**

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <p>Date:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="dateasc" autocomplete="off"  <?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'dateasc') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> <label for="dateasc">Newest &rsaquo; Oldest</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="dateorder" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="datedesc" autocomplete="off" <?php if (isset($_POST['dateorder']) && $_POST['dateorder'] == 'datedesc') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /> <label for="datedesc">Oldest &rsaquo; Newest</label>

        <hr><br>    
        <p>Title:</p>   
            <input type="radio" name="title" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="Mr"  <?php if (isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == 'Mr') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label for="Mr">Mr</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="title" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="Mrs" <?php if (isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == 'Mrs') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label for="Mrs">Mrs</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="title" onclick="javascript:submit()" value="Miss" <?php if (isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['title'] == 'Miss') echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label for="Miss">Miss</label><br><br>
    <p class="clear">Clear Filters<p>
    </form>
```

---

These are the methods I have tried so far:

**Method 1:** 
Gave the form the standard html **reset button** just before the closing form tag.

**Method 2:** 
Added this line just before the closing form tag:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
```

Added this script after the closing form tag:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
```

**Method 3:** 
Within the body tag added 
`<body onload="document.refine.reset();">` and gave the form the name **refine**.

**Method 4:** 
Set input fields to autocomplete off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts to reset the form to its initial state are actually working but the problem is that, because you are submitting the form every time you click on an `input`, the page and, therefore, the form are being reloaded and the last clicked `input` now has an initial state of `checked`. So, what you need to do is to loop through all the `checked` inputs and "uncheck" them. Here's a trimed down example of one way of doing so:

```js
var inputs=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]:checked"),
    x=inputs.length;
document.querySelector("button[type=reset]").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    while(x--)inputs[x].checked=0;
    event.preventDefault();
},0);
```

```html
<form>
    <input id="option1a" name="option1" type="radio" value="a"><label for="option1a">Option 1A</label>
    <input checked id="option1b" name="option1" type="radio" value="b"><label for="option1b">Option 1B</label>
    <input id="option1c" name="option1" type="radio" value="c"><label for="option1c">Option 1C</label>
    <hr>
    <input id="option2a" name="option2" type="radio" value="a"><label for="option2a">Option 2A</label>
    <input checked id="option2b" name="option2" type="radio" value="b"><label for="option2b">Option 2B</label>
    <input id="option2c" name="option2" type="radio" value="c"><label for="option2c">Option 2C</label>
    <hr>
    <button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Shaggy, I found this the best solution and it worked in the way that I wanted.

Comment: Why would you loop through the inputs when form.reset() will do it for you? Also you have a bug where the radio buttons will uncheck themselves if you press clear without changing anything...

Answer (score 4):

by using jQuery prop() you checked or unchecked the radio button easily .

```
 $('Radio-button').prop('checked', false);
```

By using JavaScript you have to do like this

```
 document.getElementById("Radio-button").checked=false
```

Comment: Thanks Hassan Ali, do I have to give each radio button a unique id? Or can I run the JavaScript  that it sees the type as radio button.  Tried it with the following: <script>
function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("Ascending").checked = false;
}
</script>

Comment: you can work with class because if you use id then you have to give them  unique id's to both radio buttons .Please accept it as answer if you are satisfied. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Works fine with id, but with class nothing happens.  I expect I have an error in the code.  This is what I have: The form button: <button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck "Ascending"</button>  and the script: <script>
function uncheck() {
    document.getElementByClassName("Ascending").checked = false;
}
</script>

Comment: Please use jquery instead of javascript its easy .

Comment: Thanks Hassan Ali, I don't really know jQuery, I knew just enough to get the second JavaScript option working using the ID, but I had to copy and paste the line and change the ids for each radio button.  However, for those that understand JQuery, JavaScript better than I, this answer is useful.

Comment: You should unquote `false` in your js snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<form action="" class="form" method="post">
```

on javascript you should use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".form input[type=radio]").each(function () {
$(this).prop('checked', false);
   });
});
```

[check here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q21dy32v/)

Comment: I must be missing something, this does not uncheck the form when I try it out.

Comment: have you apply class="form" in <form action="" class="form" method="post">

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q21dy32v/  go and check here see by default i checked each radio but on page load no one is checked

Comment: Thanks Suyash Singh, yes, I added the class of form.  the jsfiddle is not working, it aborts when I run it.

Comment: On my own code when I add your solution, it instantly deselects.

Comment: if you want to clear selection when function call put it
 $(".form input[type=radio]").each(function () {
$(this).prop('checked', false);
   });
in a function and call that function
if like please up vote or accept my solution